# Titles for each wrapped plots created from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, lapply

I have a list of dataframes `(datalist)` and I have created wrapped plots with `geom_line` in ggplot however I am struggling to assign to each plot its title (BA0, OG0, ON0, etc.).

```
List of 27  
$ BA0  :'data.frame':   14587 obs. of  2 variables:
   ..$ V1  : int [1:14587] 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
   ..$ V2  : int [1:14587] 43 45 46 48 49 53 55 56 57 58 ...

  $ OG0   :'data.frame':    7925 obs. of  2 variables:
   ..$ V1  : int [1:7925] 1 1 1 1 1 2 5 7 4 10 ...
   ..$ V2  : int [1:7925] 43 53 84 88 90 91 92 93 94 95 ...

  $ ON0   :'data.frame':    8347 obs. of  2 variables:
   ..$ V1  : int [1:8347] 1 2 10 6 6 3 11 6 6 6 ...
   ..$ V2  : int [1:8347] 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 ...
```

Here's the code

```
names(datalist) <- c("BA0", "OG0", "ON0", ...)

graph<-lapply(datalist,function(x)      
  p<-ggplot(x,aes(x= V2,y= V1)) +
    geom_line(colour = "blue") + 
    labs(x = "read length", y="occurences") +
    scale_x_continuous(n.breaks =10) +
    scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 8) 
) 
wrap_plots(graph)
```

I have tried to add to `p` the options:

```
ggtitle(datalist$file) ## here I added an extra column to each df corresponding to the names: BA0, OG0, ON0 etc..
ggtitle(names(datalist))
labs(title = names(datalist))
```

But I only get to have the same title for each plots, BA0, which is the first element of the list

[image]

How can I add the correct titles? Or maybe there is a better way to create this serie of plots?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: The standard way to do this in R is to use `Map` instead of `lapply`. This allows you to iterate through multiple lists or vectors such as `datalist` and `names(datalist)` instead of just a single one like `lapply` does. The other option is to do `lapply` with `seq_along(datalist)` and index into `datalist` and `names(datalist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `enframe` the list of data frames into a table and create a new column `title` using the function `dplyr::mutate`. Then you can use `purrr::pmap` to map elements of columns to a function formula creating the plot. Lastly, the plot column can be feed into `patchwork::wrap_plots`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

data <-
  list(
    iris1 = iris,
    iris2 = iris
  )

str(data)
#> List of 2
#>  $ iris1:'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>   ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ iris2:'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>   ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

data %>%
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(
    title = paste0("Fancy title ", name),
    plt = list(title, value) %>% pmap(~ {
      .y %>%
        ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_line() +
        labs(title = .x)
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(plt) %>%
  wrap_plots()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Alternatively, one can also create an explicit function for plotting:

```r
my_plot <- function(title, data) {
  data %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = title)
}

data %>%
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(
    title = paste0("Fancy title ", name),
    plt = list(title, value) %>% pmap(my_plot)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   name  value          title             plt   
#>   <chr> <list>         <chr>             <list>
#> 1 iris1 <df [150 × 5]> Fancy title iris1 <gg>  
#> 2 iris2 <df [150 × 5]> Fancy title iris2 <gg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `facet_wrap` might be suitable. You can try

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

#from list to dataframe, adding name of list item as column
dt <- rbindlist(datalist, idcol = TRUE)

#plot using facet_wrap
ggplot(dt,aes(x= V2,y= V1)) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue") + 
  labs(x = "read length", y="occurences") +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks =10) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 8) +
  facet_wrap(~.id)
```